# Retrieve Path by Wildcard in custom taget CmakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake, target, conan

I'm trying to create a custom target in a CmakeList.txt which I'm planning to execute during the build process with Conan. When executing the build with `conan build` the sources are compiled and built, creating an output file with a dynmic name and a `.a` file extensions. Now my question is how is it possible to retrieve the path to this `.a` file?

I've tried things like this:
`set(A_FILE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/*.a)` or `file(GLOB A_FILE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/*.a)`

But unfortunately both variants do not resolve the wildcard character and I end up with a path that is not usable. Is there any way to retrieve a path with the file extensions and some wildcards in a custom target?

This target would be executed after the build process has finished and produced the `*.a` file.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I.e. what is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: The GLOB should work. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Well my company uses a self-made CLI tool to modify the *.a file after its production. Now I want to integrate this modification in the build process and avoid having to do it manually, but to call the CLI in the custom target with cmake's ```COMMAND``` i have to retrieve the path to this file first.

Comment: *This target would be executed after the build process has finished and produced the \*.a file* - this is a wrong assumption. `set` and `file` do not work on the build phase.

Comment: So is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried coding that functionality in Python, directly in the recipe ``build()`` method, instead in the CMakeLists.txt?  Maybe you can call ``self.run("yourclitool ...)`` after the build is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to manipulate created library after it is built, you can use `add_custom_command` with generator expressions:

```
#create library
add_library(my_lib STATIC my_lib.cpp)

# list the contents of a newly created library
add_custom_command(
    TARGET my_lib 
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ar -t $<TARGET_FILE:my_lib>
    )
```

Note the `$<TARGET_FILE:my_lib>`; it is a generator expression that will retrieve the full path to the target `my_lib`.

BTW, trying to guess/figure-out library path in a configure phase (i.e. during cmake run) is wrong, and will almost never work correctly. Instead, use "generator expressions" to retrieve the required data.

At the end, here is the documentation about [add_custom_command(build_events)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.24/command/add_custom_command.html?highlight=add_custom_command#build-events), and [generator expressions (target queries)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html?highlight=generator%20expressions#target-dependent-queries).

Comment: This is 100% the right way of doing things. +1 for an answer that is surgically precise and does not involve globs.